got unknown error when try to install pli
i got error when i want to install pli on PyCharm.
actually i know that my PyCharm can't specify the version of pli and that's the problem.
i try pip install pli or try to add via python packages but I wasn't successful.
enter image description here
as you can see i got error when i want to install it.
enter image description here
I've tried many ways such as using terminal command or try to install it graphically but it haven't installed.

Are you sure you want to install that 17 years old pre-alpha lib and not something else?

to add upon what @KlausD. said, you want to install Pillow instead

The pli package, as stated by pypi.org/project/pli/0.0.209, was published at the 22.12.2007. It may not be working with your python version.
Please first check if correct Python version is installed by running the following command:
python -V

